# Can't reconnect to socket.io without closing and reopening app

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, socket.io

I have an iOS app that uses https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift to connect to a socket.io server.

If I open then put my app in the background while in my house connected to wifi and then walk out and down the street out of range of the wifi and then open the app I lose connection. Despite the app attempting to reconnect repeatedly, it won't reconnect.  I've verified that it is trying to reconnect using breakpoints. Only shutting the app and restarting it will it connect. However, if I simply turn off wifi with the app in the background it stays connected (switches quickly to cellular I'm assuming). If I turn on airplane mode and then turn it off again it reconnects.

The same code is called whether it is a connect at startup or a reconnect. Here is the pertinent code:

```
if( socketIOSwift != nil ) { [socketIOSwift disconnect]; 
[socketIOSwift removeAllHandlers]; 
socketIOSwift = nil; }

socketIOSwift = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url config:@{@"secure": @YES, @"log": @YES, @"forceWebsockets": @YES, @"cookies": cookies, @"ForceNew": @YES, @"ReconnectAttempts": @50, @"connectParams": properties}];
```

I've been thinking that it was the client, but now I'm wondering if it is socket.io.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had some  similar problem on heroku with free dyno, they just shut down the droplet when no one is using and all the connections are lost, and when you reconnect they restart your droplet.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by droplet?  If you mean shut down and restart the server that would not be an option.